# how to change a column with some information in the data set?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have columns household , persons in each household, tour (each tour contains different trips for each person) , trip (number of trips in each tour) , and mode ( mode of travel of each person in each trip)

I want change mode column with respect of tour column as the following

mood== car   if there exist at least one trip in the tour with mode car

mood==non-car if non of trips in a tour has mode=car

example:

```
   household.  person.  trip.   tour.    mode
       1         1        1       1       car
       1         1        2       1       walk
       1         1        4       1       bus
       1         1        1       2       bus
       1         1        2       2       walk
       1         2        1       1       walk
       1         2        2       1       bus
       1         2        3       1       walk
       2         1        1       1       walk
       2         1        1       1       car
```

output

```
   household.  person.  trip.   tour.    mode
       1         1        1       1       car
       1         1        2       1       car
       1         1        4       1       car
       1         1        1       2       non-car
       1         1        2       2       non-car
       1         2        1       1       non-car
       1         2        2       1       non-car
       1         2        3       1       non-car
       2         1        1       1       car
       2         1        1       1       car
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can group by 'household.', 'person.', 'tour.' and change the 'mode' to two values by checking if there are `any` 'car' in the column.  In that case, convert it to a numeric index by adding 1 (TRUE -> 2, FALSE ->1) and based on this index, we pass a `vector` of strings to replace the index

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(household., person., tour.) %>%
    mutate(mode = c('non-car', 'car')[1+any(mode == "car")])
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   household., person., tour. [4]
#   household. person. trip. tour. mode   
#        <int>   <int> <int> <int> <chr>  
# 1          1       1     1     1 car    
# 2          1       1     2     1 car    
# 3          1       1     4     1 car    
# 4          1       1     1     2 non-car
# 5          1       1     2     2 non-car
# 6          1       2     1     1 non-car
# 7          1       2     2     1 non-car
# 8          1       2     3     1 non-car
# 9          2       1     1     1 car    
#10          2       1     1     1 car
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(household. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L), person. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    trip. = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), tour. = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mode = c("car", "walk", 
    "bus", "bus", "walk", "walk", "bus", "walk", "walk", "car"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: it gives me NA and non-car

Comment: @sherek_66 Is it using the same data in my post?  If you have `NA` elements in your "mode", use `[1+ ("car' %in% mode)]`

Comment: I found my mistake! sorry